# Google-Maps-For-Rails not showing map in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, gmaps4rails

I am trying to use the gem 'gmaps4rails'. I inserted all of the necessary code into my model and view, and I know that the geocoding is working. However, when I insert the code `<%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>` into my `index.html.erb` file, the map does not appear.

EDIT: I downgraded the version to `0.8.8`, and I was able to run 
`rails g gmaps4rails:install` to get the layouts. Does version `0.9.1` have a different command for installing the layouts?

Comment: Mmmmm, I'll check this tomorrow

Comment: My bad for the generator, I moved it by mistake. Do you still have the bug: map not showing?

Comment: i am also having the same problem. just installed the gem n get the same thing

Comment: @apneadiving I will try it now to see if it shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem (couldn't get the generator installing) and getting the 404 for gmaps4rails.js.

The following steps worked (you had most of it).

- I downgraded to 0.8.8;
- ran the generator;
- then copied the generated files from public/ to assets/;
- changed back to version 0.9.1.

and it worked fine after that (i.e. map showing).